# Cannot return arrow function from logical or ||

Tags: javascript, syntax, logical-operators, arrow-functions

I have a scenario where I may not know if a certain object property is defined or not.  If it is, it should be a function, and it should be called.  If it is undefined, a backup function is created.  I am doing this with logical `||`:

```js
  // handleGetData may be undefined:
  const { handleGetData, ActionCreators } = fromSomewhere; 

  const getData =
    handleGetData ||
    function () {
      dispatch(
        ActionCreators.GetData({
          params: params
        })
      );
    };

  getData()
```

This seems to work just fine, except that eslint complains about an `Unexpected unnamed function`  But the syntax breaks when I try to return an arrow function after the `||`:

```js
  const getData =
    handleGetData ||
    () => {             // <------  Parsing error: Expression expected
      dispatch(
        ActionCreators.GetData({
          params: params
        })
      );
    };
```

Why is this?  If `handleGetData` is not defined, shouldn't the value of `getData` then become the arrow function, and still be callable?

#### [Codesandbox showing the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-platform-ruh1d?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: _"getData may be undefined"_... don't you mean `handleGetData`? You shouldn't be overwriting `getData` which is a `const`

Comment: You can't redefine a `const`.

Comment: Oops, you guys are correct, I edited the question

Comment: Try putting parentheses around the arrow function.

Comment: That's working!  Thanks Barmar!

Comment: Also, the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) might be a better fit than `||`

Comment: Ah, you must have the [func-names](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names) rule enabled. If you want to use your original code, you could just remove that rule

Comment: @Phil …or write `handleGetData || function getData() { … }`

Answer (score 1):

Putting parantheses around the function will solve the syntax error:

```
const getData =
  handleGetData ||
  (() => {
    dispatch(
      ActionCreators.GetData({
        params: params,
      })
    );
  });
```

The eslint error is likely caused by the `func-names` rule (see this [link](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names) for more details).
You can fix it by adding a function name, such as `handleGetDataFallback`:

```
const getData2 =
  handleGetData ||
  function handleGetDataFallback () {
    dispatch(
      ActionCreators.GetData({
        params: params,
      })
    );
  };
```